# External Hive table from AVRO files says it has no data

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro

I created an external Hive table that points to a location that has several `avro` files.  The create statement worked without any issues and it created the expected columns.  However, the table is has no data when I try to run a query.  I tried to create the table a few different ways and couldn't get it to work.  I have also verified the the directory has the `avro` files.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' 
STORED as INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat' 
LOCATION '/path/to/avro/data/' 
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='/path/to/schema/ags.avsc');

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' 
STORED as AVRO
LOCATION '/path/to/avro/data/' 
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='/path/to/schema/ags.avsc');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your statement looks correct 
unless  LOCATION '/path/to/avro/data/'  had different data also with ags.svro data? 
or
Make sure format between schema and data file is same.

Comment: the schema is in another location.  I believe the schema is the same since I grabbed the schema from the top of the avro file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the schema file(which was produced by sqoop) was incorrect.  I ended up creating a new schema file by using "avro-tools getschema "  Once I used that schema file everything worked as expected.